# CSS calc() convert decimals to pixels

Tags: css, css-variables

I'm trying to achieve css parallax effect via css-variables privided by [scroll-out](https://scroll-out.github.io) script.
Basically what script does - it sets `--viewport-y` css variable which I want to rely when calculating `top` value for image. The problem is `--viewport-y` values are decimals - e.g. `0.861`, `0.034` etc

How do I get pixels value from this values?

I created snippet to demonstrate the issue where I changing opacity easily, but unable to set `left` property

```css
body {
  --test: 0.5;
}

.container {
  background: yellow;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: calc( var(--test));
  left: calc( 100 * var(--test))px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: use % instead of pixels?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move `px` inside the `calc` expression, like this:

```css
body {
  --test: 0.5;
}

.container {
  background: yellow;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: calc( var(--test));
  left: calc( 100px * var(--test));
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Using decimal values for `px` is perfectly fine. But the way you are using `calc` with units is wrong. You should do it as follows:

```css
body {
  --test: 0.5;
}

.container {
  background: yellow;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: calc(var(--test));
  left: calc(100px * var(--test));
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

The reason it works like that is that you can mix different units within `calc`. For example `calc(100% - 10px)`.